# Hot to read variable that is outside dynamically added script element?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, dom

I add scripts dynamically to my page using next code:

```
var newScriptElem = document.createElement("script");
newScriptElem.innerHTML = myJSCodeString; // myJSCodeString loaded before from .js separate file.
parentElement.appendChild(newScriptElem);
```

The code inside does get called and works mostly fine, but I'm not able to get any variables outside that block. I have one singleton object loaded before by manually added using `<script src="app.js">` tag. It has global variable, that I want to read.

It works fine if I add the code in script tag right inside HTML file, but it does not work if I try to get it from dynamically loaded script.

Here is what app.js looks like, basically:

```
var app = new App();
function App(){
  this.someVar = 2;
}
```

This one does work

```
<body>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
   <script>
     console.log(app); // Outputs App Obj
   </script>
</body>
```

But this does not:

```
var newScriptElem = document.createElement("script");
newScriptElem.innerHTML = "console.log(app)"; // Outputs "undefined"
parentElement.appendChild(newScriptElem);
```

Is there any way to read global variables from a scope of a dynamically added script element?

P.S. I try to use Cordova, by the way, but it does not work in Chrome browser anyway..

Comment: Where does `myJSCodeString` come from? Why do you put it inside a script tag instead of simply `eval()`ing it?

Comment: Can you show the complete code, please, as a [mcve]? None of your snippet shows how the object is "*loaded before by manually added using `<script src="my.js">` tag.*"

Comment: @Bergi Added basic app.js (my.js) code.

Comment: Oh you meant *app.js* not *my.js*. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you put the code that creates and appends the `newScriptElem`, also just in a `<script>` below the `<script src="js/app.js">`?

Comment: Did You append the dynamic script to the `head`...?

Comment: @Bergi No, it looks like I add <script> inside a <div>, that is before <script scr="app.js">. But the code executes after I call app.js, because I add the script right after I load app.js.

Comment: @deblocker No, I add dynamic script inside a div, wich is inside body structure.

Comment: Just FYI - what you are doing is script injection, html's biggest security issue. Instead of trying to do this, you should be working to try to shut it down (see content-security-policy) and find other ways to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @ControlAltDel Yeah, but I make this prototype for a mobile using cordova, so I guess I can ignore security for now. But thank you for an advice!

Comment: So, I fixed one error in my app.js code and it started to work for some reason. Maybe there was a syntax error or something, so it did not work as expected.. Not sure though..

Answer (score 0):

In your question you are not appending the script that you have generated.

```html
<script>
var foo = 1;
var newScriptElem = document.createElement("script");
newScriptElem.innerHTML = `console.log(${foo});`;
document.body.append(newScriptElem);
console.log("loaded");
</script>
```

Comment: I actually add this using parentElement.appendChild(newScriptElem);. Just forgot to mention it :( The code does work as I mentioned, but global variables are undefined. Edited my question.

Comment: @AlexanderBlintsov what is `parentElement`?

Comment: Another element. A div.

Comment: @AlexanderBlintsov I think you will need to create a snippet that is reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, as @Bergi mentioned, is to call `eval(myJSCodeString)`, instead of adding it as a `<script>` block.

That way the code will be executed as is, and global variables will be accessible.